# Ordering an sapply list output in R

Tags: r

I am having problems understanding how you can ordering the output of a `sapply` list based on the column headings.  I want to calculate the % of each raster type within a polygon.  This is almost identical to the example/problem from Curlew in Get Raster Values from a Polygon Overlay in Opensource GIS Solutions and thecrashlandingdodo in Step-by-step: How do I extract Raster values from Polygon overlay with Q-GIS or R? but I am experiencing an issue with a `sapply` output.  Essentially I can't "fix" the raster value % to the correct column in my summarised table, issue shown below.

I am using R 3.2.3 x 64 via RStudio on a windows 7 machine.

My code is

```
require("raster")
require("rgdal")

# This is a simple 1m (grid) raster with 4 numerical types 1, 2, 3, 5. 
Rast <- raster('SpeciesType.tif')  

# polygon data same extent as raster dataset
Vec <- readOGR(dsn="K:/Data", layer="StudyAreas") 

extra <- extract(Rast, Vec)

extra.count <- sapply(extra, table) 

# The % of each raster numerical value within the polygon area
extra.list <- sapply(extra.count, FUN=function(x){ x / sum(x) } ) 

extra.percent <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(extra.list,'[',1:length(unique(Rast)))))
```

So the first list (`extra.list`) is correct I.e. % of each numerical raster type in a polygon e.g.

```
head(extra.list)

[[1]]

         1          2          5 

0.30587297 0.02657454 0.66755248 

[[2]]

          1           5 

0.007246377 0.992753623 

[[3]]

5 

1 

[[4]]

5 

1 

[[5]]

        1         5 

0.2806617 0.7193383 

[[6]]

5 

1
```

But the `sapply` list does not put the raster value % into the correct column headings e.g. the % in polygon of numerical value 5 is in column 5, then 2, then 1 in the first three rows.

```
head(extra.percent)

            1          2         5 NA

1 0.305872974 0.02657454 0.6675525 NA

2 0.007246377 0.99275362        NA NA

3 1.000000000         NA        NA NA

4 1.000000000         NA        NA NA

5 0.280661723 0.71933828        NA NA

6 1.000000000         NA        NA NA
```

How can I alter the data frame/sapply statement to fix this?

```
extra.percent <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(extra.list,'[',1:length(unique(Rast)))))
```

Comment: Use `tabulate` with `nbins=5` instead of `table` so that you get constant-length vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rbind.fill` from the [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) package:

```
x <- list(setNames(c(0.30587297, 0.02657454, 0.66755248), c(1, 2, 5)),          
          setNames(c(0.007246377, 0.992753623), c(1, 5)),
          setNames(1, 5),
          setNames(1, 5),
          setNames(c(0.2806617, 0.7193383), c(1, 5)),
          setNames(1, 5))


plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(x, function(v) as.data.frame(t(v))))

         1       2      5
1 0.305873 0.02657 0.6676
2 0.007246      NA 0.9928
3       NA      NA 1.0000
4       NA      NA 1.0000
5 0.280662      NA 0.7193
6       NA      NA 1.0000
```

Comment: Apologies but I don't seem to be able to vote up your answer.